# Local nginx custom url

Tags: nginx

Can someone help me convert this apache file to nginx. The bit I am after the most is 'neptix' as the sitename.. So in a browser I could go to something like: neptix/about-us,  neptix/contact-us. NOTE: No .com

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName neptix
    ServerAlias *.neptix

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass /api http://52.35.118.165/api
    ProxyPassReverse /api http://52.35.118.165/api

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/

    <Location /api>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>

    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It's unclear what's the problem you're asking about.

Comment: I am trying to setup ServerName/ServerAlias with 'sitename' and not 'sitename.com' .. so in a browser I can type   sitename and it goes to localhost:3000.   If i clicked on page the url would be   'sitename/about-us'

Comment: Your browser needs to know where to go when you enter "sitename", which can not be done in the nginx config. To make that work on your own computer you can add an entry to your hosts file (/etc/hosts on linux/OSX, probably C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts on windows) mapping sitename to the ip of that server. You won't be able to do that for everyone as you can't just define your own domains.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help (it probably needs some small tuning):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name .neptix;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://52.35.118.165/api;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```