# How to add custom PHP locations on Nginx

Tags: php, nginx, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I've configured a Yii2 advanced template site (advanced meaning 2 sites: first is frontend site and the second is the admin area)

My frontend (Nginx's root) is at /public_html and my admin is at /public_html/admin.

Almost everything works with the exception of two endpoints that were developed in a "different way".

**I think this is were my problem resides: Usually any request will point to [www.mysite.com/](http://www.mysite.com/)<controller_name>/index and the index.php file will take the request, and let PHP decide what to do given the application routes.**

**Unfortunately I have two endpoints (one in frontend and another in admin) that are [www.mysite.com/](http://www.mysite.com/)<controller_name>/action** (mind index was replaced by action). So now Nginx is routing that request to index but should be pointing it to action. Or at least this is how I see it. Amiright?

Here's what I mean:

**regular frontend routes**

- Request URL: [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com)/index
- all route to public_html/index.php but served by Nginx `location /`

**regular admin routes**

- Request URL: [www.mysite.com/admin/](http://www.mysite.com/admin/)index
- all route to public_html/admin/index.php but served by Nginx `location /admin`

**non-regular frontend route:**

- Request URL: [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com)/*not_index*  *<== I think this is my problem*
- route to public_html/index.php **still served** by Nginx `location /` *<== I think this is my problem*

**non-regular backend route:**

- Request URL: [www.mysite.com/admin/](http://www.mysite.com/admin/)*not_index*  *<== I think this is my problem*
- route to public_html/admin//index.php **still served** by Nginx `location /admin` *<== I think this is my problem*

---

"Obviously" my two non-regular routes are resolving to 404 not found. And I'm not able to find a solution for this. I've been at it for several days now...

Here's my nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    root /var/www/mysite/public_html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name localhost;

    location /admin {
        root /var/www/mysite/public_html/admin;
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri  /admin/index.php$is_args$args ;

        location = /admin/ {
            return  301 /admin;
        }

        location = /admin/frontend-users/search-influencers {
            try_files  /admin/$uri /admin/$uri.php;
        }
    }


    location / {
        root /var/www/mysite/public_html;
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~* \.(css|map|mp3|mp4|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp|ico|mov|swf|pdf|zip|rar)$ {
        access_log  off;
        log_not_found  on;
        try_files  $uri /public_html/$uri =404;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Read your question several times and can't understand what you are trying to explain. What is *non-regular* route, how is it different from *regular*, and how should it be served?

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238377/nginx-location-priority

Comment: `root /var/www/mysite/public_html/admin;` looks wrong, you should delete all of the `root` directives **except** the one in the `server` block.

Comment: maybe you need like this
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38975970/local-nginx-custom-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38975970/local-nginx-custom-url)

Comment: @IvanShatsky: I've updated my description. Is it clearer now? Thanks you

Comment: Do you mean that `/admin/frontend-users/search-influencers` is an example of such a route? What PHP script should serve this request instead of `/admin/index.php`?

Comment: @IvanShatsky route /admin/frontend-users/*search-influencers* should serve https://example.com/admin/frontend-users/search-influencers

Comment: Did you understand my question? Should request `https://example.com/admin/frontend-users/search-influencers` go to `/var/www/mysite/public_html/admin/index.php` PHP script or to some other PHP script?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `try_files  /admin/$uri /admin/$uri.php;` directive? Process the request with `/var/www/mysite/public_html/admin/frontend-users/search-influencers.php` file?

Comment: @IvanShatsky request https://example.com/admin/users -> /var/www/mysite/public_html/admin/users/index -> location /admin | request https://example.com/admin/groups -> /var/www/mysite/public_html/admin/groups/index | ... | but request https://example.com/admin/frontend-users/search -> /var/www/mysite/public_html/admin/frontend-users/search -> location /admin | and I think the /search is the problem cuz Nginx expects /index

Comment: @IvanShatsky /var/www/mysite/public_html/admin/frontend-users/search-influencers.php I am trying to override the location /admin because the aforementioned problem

Comment: @IvanShatsky I've add more details to your answer, but StackOverflow doesnt let me mention you there

Comment: @IvanShatsky updated

Comment: Sorry, I'm completely lost with your explanations. You can define almost every processing rule you could imagine with nginx config, rewrite any URI to whatever you want, add/remove query arguments, process different requests with different PHP files etc, but I'm really can't figure what nginx rules do you want. Initially I thought you want some requests to be processed by some PHP script other than `index.php`. From all our conversation I can't even figure if it is true of not. Giving up. Sorry. Looks like my answer is useless so I remove it.